# How to use node module? SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: javascript, npm, jsonp

I'm trying to use fetch-jsonp, so I type npm i fetch-jsonp to download it and its in my package.json dependencies. Then I try to import it using:

```
import fetchJsonp from 'fetch-jsonp';
```

at the top of my main.js but it keep getting this error:

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

What is causing this? My file structure is:

JS -> main.js

node_modules -> fetch-jsonp

.gitignore

index.html

package.json

Comment: "top level" means "not inside a function"

Comment: I wrote that import line at the top of my js file. "main.js:1" is beside the error in the console

Comment: Seems unlikely, but perhaps it's a problem in the fetch-jsonp package?

Answer (score 0):

Type the script as a module where you reference it. Like so:

```
<script src="/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415925) for further information.