# Issue with importing class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I want to use inheritance between classes that are in separate .js (but same folder), but i have this errors

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: TableWithFunction is not defined

Here goes my code:

```
// Table.js

export default class Table {

    constructor(name, h_cols) {
       table_id = name + 'table';
       hidden_cols = h_cols;
       table = setTable();
    }

    setTable() {...};

    setColumnDefs() {...};

{

// TableWithFunction.js

import Table from 'Table';

class TableWithFunction extends Table {

    constructor (name, h_cols) {
        super(name, h_cols);
        selected_id = name + 'Selected';
    }
    //More methods ..
}

//test.blade.php (im using laravel framework)

<script src="{{ url('js/TableWithFunction.js') }}" ></script>
<script>
    roleTable = new TableWithFunction('role',[2, 4]);
    userTable = new TableWithFunction('user',[3]);
</script>
```

I also tried to do `import Table from 'Table.js';` instead of `import Table from 'Table';`

And i tried changing Table.js using `class Table { ... } export default Table` instead of `export default class Table {...}`   and it didn't fix it, of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES2015 import doesn't work (even at top-level) in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37624819/218196)

Comment: Can you try with `import Table from '.\Table';`?

Comment: `<script src="{{ url('js/TableWithFunction.js') }}" type="module"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ES6 modules in a capable browser the importing script needs to be included with `type="module"`.

```
<script src="{{ url('js/TableWithFunction.js') }}" type="module"></script>
```

This prevents browsers *not ready for modules* to load code which would only throw an error.

The opposite is also available:

```
<script src="only-for-ie.js" nomodule></script>
```

This script will be ignored by browsers capable of handling ES6 modules.

Comment: Thanks connexo, i resolve the first error, but still have Uncaught ReferenceError: TableWithFunction is not defined. I tried to do


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            roleTable = new TableWithFunction('role',[2, 4]);
            userTable = new TableWithFunction('user',[3]);
        });
    </script>


but still doesn'y work

Comment: Any JS that wants to use `TableWithFunction` will have to `import` it (which also means you'll have to add an `export` in your `TableWithFunction.js`. Modules never create global variables.