# Can't include the Cropper.js module into my code

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

To add image cropping support to one of my Flask/Jinja pages I followed the [**Cropper.js** usage example](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) on GitHub, added the CSS link to the `<head>` of my HTML page and added the following to the `<body>` of my page:

```html
<script src="/static/assets/js/plugins/cropper.min.js" type="module"></script>
<script>
    import Cropper from "cropperjs";

    const image = document.getElementById('crop_image');
    const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
        crop(event) {
            console.log(event.detail.x);
            console.log(event.detail.y);
            console.log(event.detail.width);
            console.log(event.detail.height);
            console.log(event.detail.rotate);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
            console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
        },
    });
</script>
```

The `cropper.min.js` file can be found, as I see in the Firefox 77.0.1 browser console.
However, I do get the following error message in the console:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

at the first line of the JS `<script>`:

```js
import Cropper from "cropperjs";
```

I found [here in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox) that this error might come in Firefox from missing `type="module"`, but as you can see I do have this in my code. Any other ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in?

Comment: @Charlie As stated in my posting: **Firefox 77.0.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found the solutiuon.
For the records:

I needed to **remove** the `type="module"` part from the JS script link, and **also remove** the `import Croppe` line. Having both removed it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. This solved it.

Its important to install the entire package (with all its dependencies) in the static folder of your choice. This should install the entire package in its entirety:

```
npm install cropperjs
```

Calling the module from the **dist** folder of this package will ensure all its dependencies are called. Therefore, I have the following in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css' %}">
```

and this in the scripts section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'styles/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js' %}"></script>
```

Also, like @Matthias suggested, you don't need the import statement, whether its an inline script or a different JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `type=module` on the external script but not on the script that fails due to the import being present, and `type=module` not.

so

```
<script type="module">
    import Cropper from "cropperjs";
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Doing so leads to the following error in Firefox console: "*TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: cropperjs*"

Comment: I was just copying your code. For the module name, take a look at its declaration. The error says that cropperjs is not the module declared in your cropper.min.js

Comment: After a quick look at the library documentation I guess you have to import `cropper.esm.js`    (ES Module) instead