# How can I fix 'import declarations may only be on top level` ECMAScript import errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, javascript-import

I tried following the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox) and tried to use JS module imports with the following code.

In summary, I'm trying to import a class from the `j.js` class into the `f.js` class, and call a function on an instance of said class.

I just keep getting the following errors. All files are located in the same directory.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///C:/Users/thedr/grade-calc/nuncio/j.js”.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/thedr/grade-calc/nuncio/j.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

#### HTML

```
  <html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function f() {
                alert("IT WORKS")
            }
        </script>

        <script src="f.js"></script>
        <script src="j.js" type="module"></script>
      </body>
 </html>
```

#### F.js

```
import Fudge from "./j.js"

test = new Fudge();

test.attack();
```

#### j.js

```
export default class Fudge {
    constructor() {}

    attack() {
        f();
    }
}
```

Comment: f.js doesn't have type="module on the script tag.  chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files  or use a live server

Comment: @user120242, so I have to declare all js files as being modules? I'm using Firefox

Comment: all files that use import export syntax, because it is by definition using es6 modules, yes.   cors limitations will require using a live server or for firefox disable privacy.file_unique_origin in about:config.  Note that this is a security liability and you should turn it off after you are done.  You're better off using a live server which is easily installable from most IDEs, or npx live-server if you have nodejs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make it work all you need to do is to mark both of these JS files as module in your `index.html` file and it will work fine.

```
 <html>
<body>
    <script>
        function f() {
            alert("IT WORKS")
        }
    </script>

    <script src="f.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="j.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: does not work for laravel blade templates. maybe js is getting loaded at an earlier stage, will have to digg into that