# How to Import Javascript Module from external javascript file into <script> tag of HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, figma, figma-api

I am trying to import a module called 'JSZip' from an external node package called JSZip in my HTML File.

Importing it directly using import command is not working,

```
<script>    

     import JSZip from '../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js';

</script>
```

I also tried importing it in HTML file in the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
```

But the above code is still not importing the module.

I understand this can be easily achieved if we do it directly in a javascript file, but I am building this for a figma plugin and I am constrained to do this on ui.html file because the browser APIs can be only called on the html side and the js file runs in another sandbox environment.

To read more about figma plugin's ui and js files, [you can refer this](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/how-plugins-run/)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: I'd expect the first approach to fail with an obvious error message, and the latter approach to work. How are you determining that it isn't working? What have you don't do debug it? Are errors listed on the Console? Does the Network tab show it successfully loading with the content you expect and not HTTP error?

Comment: See [Moz guide on JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37624819.

Answer (score 1):

Either import the module with `<script type="module">` (see [compatibility chart](https://caniuse.com/#search=es%20modules))...

Or, for IE & other old browsers support, use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or similar and compile all your JS into a single, minified and ES5 compatible (the old javascript) file.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

add `type="module"` to script tag. it will work.

```html
<script type="module">    
     import JSZip from '../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use webpack in this case. You get the benefit of using js imports and create small modules for your code. But when it's time to execute it, wepback will convert all that, into one single js file.

Make sure you have a `package.json` file that has `"type": "module"` and in your code you can import other js files with `import Foo from './Foo.js'` while the js files have `export default { }`

```js
// file - package.json

{
  "type": "module"
}

// file - index.js

import Foo from './Foo.js'

Foo.start()

// file - Foo.js

export default {
  start () {
    console.log('start')
  }
}

// file - webpack.config.cjs

return {
  target: 'web',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: './script.js'
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```