# Simple js function not defined in view despite file compiled and referenced

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I am trying to use a simple js function in a view and it doesn't seem the view is seeing the script I am referencing.

testFile.js:

```
export const simpleFc = (input) => {
    alert(input);
}
```

It build without error and I can see the resulted build js file and it's content is correct. I have no other js error in console.

I am including it in the view:

```
<script src="~/dist/js/testFile.build.js"></script>
```

Then I am trying to use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    simpleFc('show alert');
</script>
```

I am getting an error saying: `simpleFc` is not defined.

Comment: In `testFile.js:`, you're using `export`, meaning that you're using a module. Variables and functions defined in a module are module-scoped, meaning that they cannot be accessed outside of the module unless exported (which you've done). However, when you want to use the exported value, you need to `import` it first: `import {simpleFc} from "./testFile.js";` in the file you want to use it in

Comment: But I am using the function in a view, not a js file, so I cannot really import it. This is because I want to pass to js some razor values (like for example the alert value) and otherwise I would need to add fake elements with those values to grab on the js module side. What in this case? @NickParsons

Comment: In your view, where you have the HTML script tag: `<script type="text/javascript">`, you would instead use `<script type="module">` and `import` the function from your `testFile` module that you created and then call the imported function.

Comment: I tried. I am getting ABORTED 404 error in the console when I try to use eg. `import { Section } from '/wwwroot/src/components/shared/models/myModel';` within `<script type="module">` on this line exactly. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783429/how-to-import-javascript-module-from-external-javascript-file-into-script-tag they say that I need to add `type: module` in `package.json` but this gives another error when importing files to other js @NickParsons