# Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react app and i get the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

my index.html looks like this:

```
<html>


<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="index.js">

</script>
</body>


</html>
```

and my corresponding index.js like this:

```
import React from 'react';

console.log("test")

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>);
```

I am just trying to do a simple hello world from the react website. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES2015 import doesn't work (even at top-level) in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624819/es2015-import-doesnt-work-even-at-top-level-in-firefox)